# Fetch data as per the input name or id from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a view result page where after log in and adding details a user can view his or her profile info. But the problem is that View result shows all the database entries include the user..where I dont wish it to be. I wish the only entry of ther active user. Is the following code is sufficient? or I give the whole code

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY name DESC");
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to learn more about the Mystery of SQL.

```
$result = mysql_query(
    "SELECT * FROM users WHERE activeuser='Swati' ORDER BY name DESC"
);
```

Comment: `ORDER BY` is useless here since it returns only one row.

Comment: I'm not entering into specific into an Answer because the query could be for any table, therefor i'm avoiding of changing the whole SQL although it's "users" and only patching the needed result.
If the Asker want to change his Query to more sufficient he is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `WHERE` statement such as `WHERE UserID=$_SESSION['UserID']`